# Ngrok - HTTP 400 with virtualhost

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, ngrok

I have created a url in ngrok integrated in my webhook of stripe.
But when I call that url, I receive a HTTP 400.

I have a domain name attached to my localhost url: `abc.com:port` and i have registered that address in my host-file. I executed ngrok like this: `ngrok http port` which gives me `localhost:port`.

What might be the issue for it?

Comment: Try starting `ngrok` like this: `ngrok http -host-header=abc.com 80`, replace 80 with your port.

Comment: It worked @Jeppe Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs#virtual-hosts) on how you can *"ask ngrok to rewrite the Host header of all tunneled requests to match what your web server expects."*

> *"For example, to route to your local site myapp.dev, you would run: 
>   `ngrok http -host-header=myapp.dev 80`"*